# Show that $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ is not compact by definition

Tags: general-topology, analysis, manifolds, compactness

I want to show by definition that $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ is not compact, so I did this:

Let ${\Omega}$ be an open cover of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and suppose that $\mathbb{R^n}$ is compact, then there exists a finite subcollection of ${\Omega}_{i=1}^{k}$ such that $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ is covered by $\Omega_{i=1}^{k}$. So, ${\cup}_{i=1}^{k}\Omega_{i}$ $\supseteq \mathbb{R^{n}}$.

From this part, I don't know how to continue the proof, I think the last argument is a contradiction but I'm not quite sure. Can you help me? Please.

Comment: You don't want a proof by contradiction. Come up with a particular open cover of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that has no finite subcover.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint:** If you want to show that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is *not* compact, you just need to provide a specific example of an open cover that has no finite subcover.

Try with the open cover $\{\Omega_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, where $\Omega_{k}$ is the open ball of radius $k$, centred at $\mathbf{0}$.

(By the way, this is an example of the general principle that to show that something is *not* always true, giving a specific counterexample is sufficient.)

Comment: If I was asked to show it by definition then using a counterexample is not by definition, right? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: Well the definition of "$X$ is compact" is "every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover". Therefore, the definition of "$X$ is not compact" is "there exists an open cover of $X$ that has no finite subcover". Hence to show $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not compact by definition, you just need to show that *there exists* an open cover of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with no finite subcover. To show an existence like this, an explicit example is sufficient.

Comment: You are asked to prove that the definition of compactness does not hold for $\mathbb R^n$. To do this, you prove that the *negation* of the definition of compactness is *true*. When you negate the definition, you come up with the statement "there exists an open cover that has no finite subcover". To prove something exists, you simply have to find an example.

Comment: Open cover in the definition assumes the set you give is countable. But the set R is not countable so how you create a cover.

Answer (score 2):

How about the open cover consisting of the open balls of radius $1$:  $\mathscr C=\{B(r,1)\mid r\in\Bbb R^n\}$?

I don't think there's a finite subcover.

For suppose we have a finite subcollection:  $\mathscr F=\{B(r_k,1)\mid k=1,\dots,n\}$.

Take a point $x\in\Bbb R^n$ with distance from the origin $d(x,0)\gt\max \{1+d(r_k,0)\mid k=1,\dots,n\}$.  You can do this because $\Bbb R^n$ is unbounded.   (I guess technically you need the Archimedean principle for this.)

Then $x\not\in B(r_k,1)$ for any $B(r_k,1)\in\mathscr F$.